# embed a script into Google Slides Using Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I'm trying to embed interactive content into Google Slides from an application called Genial.ly. What I'm trying to do is:

1. I copy an HTML script on Genial.ly
2. I then open the script editor on Google Slides>Tools.
3. I then past the script and run it. I get this message:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (line 2, file "Code.gs")

4. I'm stuck, not sure what next steps are, not even sure what I'm trying to do is even possible

Here's the script I'm trying to embed into Google Slides:

```
<div class="container-wrapper-genially" style="position: relative; min-height: 400px; max-width: 100%;"><img src="https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/genial.ly/5ed8f285d8ef906cea2515d1/4746f820-fcac-446f-b4d1-8ec8fbdabad5.png" class="loader-genially" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; margin-top: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: auto; margin-left: auto; z-index: 1;width: 80px; height: 80px;"/><div id="5f1ad697fbeabf0cf7b3c597" class="genially-embed" style="margin: 0px auto; position: relative; height: auto; width: 100%;"></div></div><script>(function (d) { var js, id = "genially-embed-js", ref = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; } js = d.createElement("script"); js.id = id; js.async = true; js.src = "https://view.genial.ly/static/embed/embed.js"; ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref); }(document));</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to embed interactively content in Google Slides. Instead use a Google Site or create a Web App.

Below is the **Insert menu** of Google Slides. As you can see there is no "embed" option there.

[image]

The Google Slides API doesn't include it either.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/slides